# How to get disk read/write speed for LVM logical partition?

Tags: linux, lvm

I'm writing an agent collecting metrics of linux server. I get disk info with kernel file `/proc/diskstats`. It works for disk type `disk` or `part`, but if disk type is `lvm` or `dm`, I cannot get `read / write sector num` fields.

```
cat /proc/diskstats 
   8       0 sda 256780 18842 6500240 2143804 28685518 19444429 595859080 177384284 0 143033129 179528537
   8       1 sda1 390 224 2932 884 15 7 56 115 0 919 999
   8       2 sda2 256041 18618 6494516 2138838 23151610 19443195 595824112 88374404 0 56461356 90589410
 253       0 dm-0 17773 0 142184 182853 118244 0 945952 37053269 0 45151 37236146
 253       1 dm-1 69000 0 2786922 465071 23902377 0 295539112 117043416 0 86738124 117508617
 253       2 dm-2 189142 0 3564794 1736523 18675050 0 299339048 248195431 0 58080383 249946740

// field 4(# of sectors read) and 8(# of sectors write) is zero for dm-0, dm-1 and dm-2

lsblk -o MAJ:MIN,NAME,PHY-SEC,LOG-SEC,TYPE,SIZE -lb
MAJ:MIN NAME            PHY-SEC LOG-SEC TYPE          SIZE
8:0     sda               512     512   disk 1000204886016
8:1     sda1              512     512   part     524288000
8:2     sda2              512     512   part  999678803968
253:0   VolGroup-lv_swap  512     512   lvm    16903045120
253:1   VolGroup-lv_root  512     512   lvm    53687091200
253:2   VolGroup-lv_home  512     512   lvm   929084473344
```

> Is there another way to get disk read/write sector or bytes for lvm
>   type?

reference: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/iostats.txt

Answer (score 1):

If you want to examine the contents of a block device and determine what is in it, you might want to look at the `blkid` tool.

Maybe this will provide you the info you're asking.

Also, there is one more thing that crossed my mind, try it with this:

```
sudo vgscan
sudo vgs
sudo vgdisplay
```